# Reversing a string

Tags: javascript

I want to reverse a string, then I want to reverse each word in it. I was able to reverse the string. But couldn't reverse words in it.

Given Str = "how are you"
Expected Result = "you are how"

My code
`var my_str="how are you";
        alert(my_str.split('').reverse().join(''));`

Result I get: `uoy era woh`

How to get the final result??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the other answers are entirely correct if your string has only 1 space between words.

if you have multiple spaces between words, then things are a bit different:
to get just the words, in reverse order, rejoined by 1 space:

```
str.split(/\s+/).reverse().join(" ")
```

to reverse the entire string, and still have the original whitespace:

```
str.split(/\b/).reverse().join('')
```

the first one uses a regex, "/\s+/", to match an entire run of spaces, instead of a single space. it rejoins the words with a single space.

the second one uses a regex, "/\b/", to just split on the boundaries between words and non-words. since the runs of spaces will be preserved, it just rejoins with an empty string.

Comment: This is the most production-worthy solution. +1

Answer (score 8):

I think you've got an empty string in there: `my_str.split('')`

Make sure you put a space: `my_str.split(' ')`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are splitting with the empty string instead of the space character. Try this:

```
var str = "how are you";
alert(str.split(" ").reverse().join(" "));
```

[Try it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/wzgxq/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6 then you could use this -

```js
    let myStr="How are you";
    console.log([...myStr].reverse().join(''));
```